# Super simple SAS prxposn example needed

Tags: regex, sas

I am looking for a super simple prxposn example that works.  Something like this, only I want code that extracts text.

```
data test;
    re = prxparse('/(hello)/');
    extract = prxposn(re,1,'hello');
    output;
run;
```

results

```
re  extract
1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
data test;
    re = prxparse('/(hello)/');
    if prxmatch(re,'hello') then extract = prxposn(re,1,'hello');
    output;
run;
```

The call to prxmatch is required for prxposn to work.

result

```
re  extract
1   hello
```

Comment: The true part of this answer is the text, not the example. *The call to prxmatch is required for prxposn to work.* That is, you do not have to do an `if then else` clause, you can also just as well assign another variable to the `prxmatch`, e.g. `test = prxmatch(re,"hello")`.